# Windows patch Automation

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I would like to Download, install patches in windows2008 and windows 2012 servers using python script. if there is any other powershell module to achieve this, it would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to use python to accomplish this task?

Comment: Hi, just curious to know if it is possible in python, if not python, powershell also fine for me. My requirement is to automate patching , pull reports from WSUS and display it in a portal, a kind of dashboard.

Comment: Powershell is a Microsoft tool so I would recommend using it over using Python.